# Backing field in Entity Framework Core 6 is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am using Entity Framework Core 6 for my application. I have a string property `TaskParameter` with a backing field. When I query it, it returns null.

```
private string _parametersJson;

[BackingField(nameof(_parametersJson))]
public TaskParameter GetParametersJson
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_parametersJson))
            return null;

        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TaskParameter>(_parametersJson);
    }
}

public void SetParametersJson(TaskParameter parametersJson)
{
    _parametersJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(parametersJson);
}
```

Comment: There's no `set` method on the property - how are you ever setting that value then??

Comment: I have added in the entity

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your code, can you share more information? It would be better if you provide a minimal reproducible example.